# Habilitar input desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes. Soy principiante con HTLM, CSS y Javascript. Adjunto el código.
No puedo hacer funcionar en Javascript que dos inputs y dos botones cambien su condición 'disabled'.
El código Javascript (lo copié) está funcionando bien para cambiar el value de un label cuando se hace click en un radio button. Le agregué funcionalidad para cambiar el disabled pero no hace nada.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const select = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
const selectLabel = document.querySelector('#select-label');

const codigo = document.querySelector('#inp-cod');
const desc = document.querySelector('#inp-desc');
const grabar = document.querySelector('#btn-grabar');
const borrar = document.querySelector('#btn-borrar');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleHidden();
})

function toggleHidden() {
    select.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

options.forEach(function(option) {
    option.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setSelectTitle(e);
    })
})

function setSelectTitle(e) {
    const labelElement = document.querySelector(`label[for="${e.target.id}"]`).innerText;
    selectLabel.innerText = labelElement;
    codigo.disabled = false;
    desc.disabled = false;
    grabar.disabled = false;
    borrar.disabled = false;
    toggleHidden();

}
```

```html
<?php

    $Resp = explode("|",'NUEVO - Nuevo tipo de Movimiento|BAJA - BAJA POR MOROSO E INTRATABLE|ALTA - ALTA DE CLIENTE NUEVO|MODI - MODIFICACION DE DATOS Y PREMISAS|RECI - RECIBO REMITO CORTO Y CHOTO|PINO - MADERA DE ARBOL CON AGUJAS');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta title="LHS - Sistema de Gestión">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Prueba3.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <h1>Maestro de Tipos de Movimiento</h1>

            <form name="formulario">

                <div class="select-group">
                    <label for="button">Tipo de Movimiento</label>
                    <button class="button" id="button">
                        <span id="select-label">Elija el Tipo de Movimiento</span>
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                    </button>

                    <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown hidden">
                        <?php foreach($Resp as $Tipo) {
                            $Pos = strpos($Tipo, '-');
                            if ($Pos !== false) {
                                $Cod = substr($Tipo, 0, $Pos - 1);
                                $Desc = substr($Tipo, $Pos + 2);
                            } else {
                                $Cod = '???';
                                $Desc = $Tipo;
                            }
                            $Uno = 'for="select-'.$Cod.'"';
                            $Dos = 'id="select-'.$Cod.'"';
                            $Tres = 'value="'.$Cod.'"';?>
                            <label class="select-item" <?php echo $Uno;?>><?php echo $Tipo;?></label>
                            <input class="option" <?php echo $Dos;?> type="radio" name="where" value="sociales">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <label for="codigo">Codigo</label>
                <input type="text" name="Codigo" id="codigo" class="inp-cod" maxlength="4" size="4" required disabled>
                <label for="desc">Descripción</label>
                <input type="text" name="Desc" id="desc" class="inp-desc" maxlength="50" size="50" required disabled>

                <input type="button" id="grabar" value="Grabar" class="btn-grabar" onclick="" disabled>
                <input type="button" id="borrar" value="Borrar" class="btn-borrar" onclick="" disabled>

            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="Prueba3.js"></script>      <!-- Código Javascript, abajo de todo, dentro de <body> -->

    </body>

</html>
```

Probé de todo (lo, muy, poco que se), probé con document.getElementById, probé con document.formulario.Codigo.disabled, etc.
El javascript no está viendo los inputs ni los botones, no se que estoy haciendo mal. les agradeceré mucho vuestra ayuda. Saludos,

Comment: No termino de entender la duda, ¿puedes explicarte mejor por favor?

Answer (score 1):

La manera de cambiar el estado del atributo "disabled" es esta:

```html
Input: <input id="campoInput" type="text" value="escriba su texto" disabled>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('campoInput').disabled = false">Habilitar</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('campoInput').disabled = true">Deshabilitar</button>
```

Básicamente, cada elemento DOM tiene unas propiedades, algunas (no todas) son booleanas y simplemente se pueden cambiar simplemente de verdadero (true) a falso (false) su valor, para activarse o desactivarse, y lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente lanzar con javascript esa acción.

```
document.getElementById('campoInput').disabled = true
```

Nota que aquí se está diciendo: del documento, dame el elemento con el "id" "campoInput", y modifica el valor de la propiedad "disabled" a verdadero.

---

Habiendo dicho esto, quiero alertarte de que jamás debes incluir código que no entiendas, al menos de una forma general, en tus páginas, porque no sabes si podría tener algún truco malvado, y además no sabrás cómo puede interactuar  y alterar el resto de tu página. Esto no significa que no puedas usar librerías o marcos de trabajo, solo me refiero específicamente a esto: copiar y pegar pequeños fragmentos sin saber qué pasa con cada uno.

Tu código PHP está innecesariamente complejo, lo que necesitas es usar "arrays" y un pequeño bucle y ya. La forma también está excesivamente revuelta, lo más sencillo en este caso es solamente hacer un menu desplegable. Y veo que quieres hacer que el usuario pueda insertar su propio movimiento, en ese caso solo necesitas un poco de javascript y ya.

```
<?php
//lista de movimientos y sus códigos
$lista = [
    'NUEVO' => 'NUEVO MOVIMIENTO: Escribir descripción',
    'BAJA' => 'BAJA POR MOROSO E INTRATABLE',
    'ALTA' => 'ALTA DE CLIENTE NUEVO',
    'MODI' => 'MODIFICACION DE DATOS Y PREMISAS',
    'RECI' => 'RECIBO REMITO CORTO Y CHOTO',
    'PINO' => 'MADERA DE ARBOL CON AGUJAS',
];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta title="LHS - Sistema de Gestión">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Prueba3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-container">
            <h1>Maestro de Tipos de Movimiento</h1>
            <form name="formulario"  action="procesar.php">
                <label for="movimientoCodigo">Código de Movimiento:</label>
                <!-- Nota aquí que hay un evento javascript que simplemente habilitará o deshabilitará la posibilidad de cambiar la descripción si es necesario -->
                <input id="movimientoCodigo" list="movimientosLista" name="codigo" onchange="actualizarDescripcion()" required>
                <datalist id="movimientosLista">
                <?php
                    //Haz un bucle con todas las opciones en el array $lista.
                    foreach ($lista as $clave => $movimiento) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $clave . '">' . "$clave: $movimiento</option>" . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                ?>
                </datalist>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //imprime la lista de movimientos para que esté también disponible en javascript
                    var movimientos = {}
                    <?php
                        
                        foreach ($lista as $clave => $movimiento) {
                            echo "movimientos['$clave'] = '$movimiento'". PHP_EOL;
                        }
                    ?>
                    //activación o no del campo de descripción
                    function actualizarDescripcion() {
                        //obtén los elementos
                        var movimientoCodigoElemento = document.getElementById('movimientoCodigo')
                        var descripcionElemento = document.getElementById('desc')
                        //revisa si el código es nuevo o es una cosa rara, y entonces activa la descripción, y corrige el código
                        var codigo = movimientoCodigoElemento.value;
                        if(codigo == 'NUEVO' || !movimientos.hasOwnProperty(codigo)) {
                            //corrige el código
                            movimientoCodigoElemento.value = 'NUEVO'
                            codigo = movimientoCodigoElemento.value;
                            //activa la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.disabled = false
                            //haz que la descripción esté vacía
                            descripcionElemento.value = null
                            //dale un valor predefinido:
                            descripcionElemento.placeholder = movimientos[codigo]
                            
                        } else {
                            //si no desactiva la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.disabled = true
                            //actualiza la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.value = movimientos[codigo]
                        }
                        
                    }
                </script>
                <label for="desc">Descripción:</label>
                <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" disabled required>
                <!-- Estos botones tienen que hacer algo, enviar la acción de la forma. -->
                <input type="submit" id="grabar" name="accion" value="grabar" class="btn-grabar">
                <input type="submit" id="borrar" name="accion" value="borrar" class="btn-borrar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ejemplo interactivo:

```html
<form name="formulario"  action="procesar.php">
                <label for="movimientoCodigo">Código de Movimiento:</label>
                <!-- Nota aquí que hay un evento javascript que simplemente habilitará o deshabilitará la posibilidad de cambiar la descripción si es necesario -->
                <input id="movimientoCodigo" list="movimientosLista" name="codigo" onchange="actualizarDescripcion()" required>
                <datalist id="movimientosLista">
                <option value="NUEVO">NUEVO: NUEVO MOVIMIENTO: Escribir descripción</option>
<option value="BAJA">BAJA: BAJA POR MOROSO E INTRATABLE</option>
<option value="ALTA">ALTA: ALTA DE CLIENTE NUEVO</option>
<option value="MODI">MODI: MODIFICACION DE DATOS Y PREMISAS</option>
<option value="RECI">RECI: RECIBO REMITO CORTO Y CHOTO</option>
<option value="PINO">PINO: MADERA DE ARBOL CON AGUJAS</option>
                </datalist>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //imprime la lista de movimientos para que esté también disponible en javascript
                    var movimientos = {}
                    movimientos['NUEVO'] = 'NUEVO MOVIMIENTO: Escribir descripción'
movimientos['BAJA'] = 'BAJA POR MOROSO E INTRATABLE'
movimientos['ALTA'] = 'ALTA DE CLIENTE NUEVO'
movimientos['MODI'] = 'MODIFICACION DE DATOS Y PREMISAS'
movimientos['RECI'] = 'RECIBO REMITO CORTO Y CHOTO'
movimientos['PINO'] = 'MADERA DE ARBOL CON AGUJAS'
                    //activación o no del campo de descripción
                    function actualizarDescripcion() {
                        //obtén los elementos
                        var movimientoCodigoElemento = document.getElementById('movimientoCodigo')
                        var descripcionElemento = document.getElementById('desc')
                        //revisa si el código es nuevo o es una cosa rara, y entonces activa la descripción, y corrige el código
                        var codigo = movimientoCodigoElemento.value;
                        if(codigo == 'NUEVO' || !movimientos.hasOwnProperty(codigo)) {
                            //corrige el código
                            movimientoCodigoElemento.value = 'NUEVO'
                            codigo = movimientoCodigoElemento.value;
                            //activa la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.disabled = false
                            //haz que la descripción esté vacía
                            descripcionElemento.value = null
                            //dale un valor predefinido:
                            descripcionElemento.placeholder = movimientos[codigo]
                            
                        } else {
                            //si no desactiva la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.disabled = true
                            //actualiza la descripción
                            descripcionElemento.value = movimientos[codigo]
                        }
                        
                    }
                </script>
                <label for="desc">Descripción:</label>
                <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" disabled required>
                <!-- Estos botones tienen que hacer algo, enviar la acción de la forma. -->
                <input type="submit" id="grabar" name="accion" value="grabar" class="btn-grabar">
                <input type="submit" id="borrar" name="accion" value="borrar" class="btn-borrar">
            </form>
```

En este caso se enviará la forma con estos parámetros, en el caso de que se elija una opción predefinida, por ejemplo, el ALTA:

```
?codigo=ALTA&accion=grabar
```

Para borrar:

```
?codigo=ALTA&accion=borrar
```

Y para un nuevo movimiento:

```
?codigo=NUEVO&desc=Texto+escrito+por+el+usuario&accion=grabar
```

Estos códigos los obtendrás en php así:

```
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'] ?? null;
$desc = $_GET['desc'] ?? null;
$accion = $_GET['accion'] ?? null;
```

Y se enviarán al destino definido en el atributo action del elemento form:

```
<form name="formulario"  action="procesar.php">
```

Comment: Estimado algo, muchas gracias por tus correcciones. Te cuento que yo trabajo con una base de datos no convencional (UniVerse). El código PHP que ves es solo para imitar lo que me devolvería la base de datos, no tiene importancia en el ejemplo. Finalmente usé: document.getElementById('campoInput').disabled = true y funcionó bien. Entiendo el código de forma general, empecé con HTML hace una semana pero tengo 40 años de desarrollador. No vi que el código fuera 'malicioso'. Con ese criterio, tu respuesta también podría ser maliciosa y yo no debería incluirla si no la entiendo perfectamente. Bye!